# TypeError: this.clusterer is undefined after Rails Model name change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, markerclusterer

I've changed my Model and Controller names and all it's connected data + filenames. Everything works except my JS GoogleMaps API that shouts:

```
TypeError: this.clusterer is undefined
```

The thing is - I tried to precompile my assets once again, I've searched through all the files and I can't find the answer. 
Do you know where are all the assets being held/changed by rake and where should I be looking for an answer?

My controller:

```
def index
    @hunts = Hunt.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@hunts) do |hunt, marker|
        marker.lat hunt.latitude
        marker.lng hunt.longitude
        marker.infowindow hunt.email
    end
end
```

View:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'hunt_map'%>
```

And JS:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap(
  { 
  provider: { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.0636153, 19.9317813), 
    zoom: 13
  }, 
  internal: { id: 'map' }
  }, 
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.addCircles(
      [{ lat: 50.0636153, lng: 19.9317813, radius: 5}],
      { strokeColor: "#000" });

  });
handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 50.0636153,
      "lng": 19.9317813,
      "picture": {
        "url": "http://www.tamu.edu/faculty/ccbn/dewitt/adp/resources/images/shamrock.gif",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "Treasure lies here!"
    }
 ]);
```

Update:
My config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( hunt_map.js )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass data to JavaScript located in `assets`. That's why you can't see your points on map, because `nil` is passed in this line

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
```

The easiest solution to your problem is to put that js directly in `viewer`. To make it in more elegant way check this [railcast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).

This `TypeError: this.clusterer is undefined` happened because you tried to call `handler.addMarkers(...)` outside of `function(){...}`. Just move it back there and error should be gone.